# SqLite.js Uncaught Error: CHECK constraint failed

Tags: sql, sqlite, check-constraints

I am trying to insert values in a table in SQLite but getting

> **SqLite.js Uncaught Error: CHECK constraint failed:
>    st** .

I am unable to find any of the errors. Can someone help to figure the error out?

Here is my create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE st(EMPLOYE_ID TEXT primary key ,  EMPLOYE_Name text NOT NULL ,
father_name text NOT NULL, cnic INTEGER NOT NULL,DOB real not null,address 
text not null,
 username text not null,password text not null, post text not null 
CHECK(typeof(employe_id)='text' AND length(employe_id)<=10 and 
(employe_name)='text'  AND 
length(employe_name)<=100 and (father_name)='text' 
 AND length(father_name)<=100  and(cnic)='integer' AND length(cnic)=13 and 
(address)='text' and length(address)<=200 
and (username)='text'
 and length(username)<=10 and (password)='text' and length(password)<=20)   
);
```

and here is my insert statement.

```
insert into st values('a1','jamshaid','iqbal',1110332507339,julianday('1998-
10-05'),'26 eb rehmkot','a1','a1','Admin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **ALWAYS SPECIFY COLUMN LIST**

```
insert into st(employe_id, employe_name, father_name, cnic, DOB, address, username, password,post)
values('a1','jamshaid','iqbal',1110332507339,julianday('1998-10-05'),'26 eb rehmkot','a1','a1','Admin');
```

---

Second  make it easier to read and debug by using formatting:

```
CREATE TABLE st(
 EMPLOYE_ID TEXT primary key ,              -- typo: employee_id, and why not INT
 EMPLOYE_Name text NOT NULL ,
 father_name text NOT NULL,
 cnic INTEGER NOT NULL,
 DOB real not null,                         -- why is DOB real and not DATE???
 address text not null,
 username text not null,
 password text not null,                    -- I hope this is not clear text
 post text not null 
CHECK(
  typeof(employe_id)='text' 
 AND length(employe_id)<=10 
 and typeof(employe_name)='text'  
 AND length(employe_name)<=100 
 and typeof(father_name)='text' 
 AND length(father_name)<=100  
 and typeof(cnic)='integer' 
 AND length(cnic)=13 
 and typeof(address)='text' 
 and length(address)<=200 
 and typeof(username)='text'
 and length(username)<=10 
 and typeof(password)='text' 
 and length(password)<=20
 )   
);
```

You could easily spot your bug that way or simply comment lines until it works.

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=f8b55eae9508b1edc31e8d63cac5e34d)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have got my error. and thanks for your suggestion. i will follow if from now.Thanks a lot...